# Equivalence arrow in LaTeX

Tags: equations, align

I have an equation like

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
 a+b+c+d+e+f&=g\\
\Leftrightarrow a &=g-a-b-c-d-e-f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to have the arrow left to both equation, how do I do this?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, the required `\usepackage`'s, `\begin{document}`, and `\end{document}`. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Do you mean like this?

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
\begin{alignat*}{2}
&\iff & a+b+c+d+e+f &=g             \\
&\iff &           a &=g-b-c-d-e-f
\end{alignat*}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I think you should clarify the reason *why* you used `\iff{}` instead of `\iff`: not only because here it's useful, but also because `\iff{}` in other places might give you “problematic” spacing. E.g., I've seen people using `\dots{}` in math.

Comment: @Manuel Actually, `{}` doesn't seem to be useful in this case, so I just removed it.

Comment: @Jubobs Yes, it's useful. You still see a space because `\iff` ensures there is some space around it… but there “should” be a `{}` there. Just imagine it's a `\to` instead of `\iff` in that case the difference is easier to spot since if you don't use `{}` you end up with no space.

Comment: @Manuel You know more than I do on the topic. Could you please edit my answer?

Comment: @Jubobs I don't know either, may be here is not necessary, but if you use (I see you edited it) `\iff{}` you should clarify why to avoid problems in text. I repeat, I don't know either.

Answer (score 6):

[image]

### Notes:

- As this is just a single equation, you don't really need to use `align`, but in case you have other equations in your actual use case I left it as `align`:

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}
If you mean to say "if, and only if" you should use \verb|\iff|:
\begin{align*}
a+b+c+d+e+f&=g \iff a =g-a-b-v-d-e-f
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```